# Request Ajax(jsonp) using Httprequest

Tags: c#

I have this request using Ajax method to get data in my javascript for front end

```
  $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  timeout: 5000, 
  cache: false, 
  async:async,  
  beforeSend: function(){       
  }, 
  complete: function(x, ts){ 
  }
```

In my back-end I am using `httpwebrequest` to get it data.

```
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Timeout = 40000;                    
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";
    req.Accept = "text/javascript,application/json, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01";
        req.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, req.Headers, new object[] { "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" });
        req.CookieContainer = httpCookie;
        req.KeepAlive = true; 
        req.Method = "GET";
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse res = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    CookiesJar.Add(res.Cookies);

    System.IO.Stream Answer = res.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Answer);
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

The back-end code is not getting any response. what wrong with it ?

Comment: `In my backend I am using httpwebrequest to get it data.` Did you just say you use `HttpWebRequest` to catch ajax request???

Comment: My back end is another application , when I need the data from the ajax request , so I request it

Comment: You may want to take a look to asp.net/xml webservices. `HttpWebRequest` class is used to get/post data from/to a specific url, not for listening clients.

Comment: this seems a little messy, you have get, but i dont see any params being passed through..

Comment: the page have no params~

Comment: ASP.Net or MVC ? What's your URL call and where is your C# code located ?

Comment: ASp.net , i am calling the URL that at others domain . where my c# code is at another server with different domain